# xml parsing doubts on iOS

Tags: ios, xml-parsing

```
<category name="Politics"> 
<item> 
<oid>2754</oid> 
<title>²XÉÄá çµÞYd·Øí ®¢ÉßÎÞV ÈÞæ{ øÞ¼ßÕÏíAá¢</title> 
<thumbImage>http://122.248.234.55/v3/repository/images/news/telangana._thuthumb_2754.jpg</thumbImage> 
<shortDescription>æÄÜCÞÈ çÎ¶ÜÏßW ÈßKáU ²XÉÄí ®¢ÉßÎÞV ÈÞæ{ øÞ¼ßØÎVMßAá¢.</shortDescription>
</item> 
<item> 
<oid>2753</oid> 
<title>ÄáGá ÕÞBáKÕøæˆKí Õß.®ØßçÈÞ¿á ¼ÏøÞ¼X</title> 
<thumbImage>http://122.248.234.55/v3/repository/images/news/MV-Jayarajan_thuthumb_2753.jpg</thumbImage> 
<shortDescription>Éß¼ß dÉçÕÖÈJßæa µÞøcJßW 50:50 ÉÞÜßAÞX µÝßEßæˆKá ¼ÏøÞ¼X ØNÄß‚á.</shortDescription>
</item> 
<item> 
<oid>2751</oid> 
<title>ÕÜßÏ ØìµøcB{ÞÏçMÞZ Ø¶ÞÕßæÈ ØßÉß®¢ ÎùKá</title> 
<thumbImage>http://122.248.234.55/v3/repository/images/news/saghavu_thuthumb_2751.jpg</thumbImage> 
<shortDescription>Éß. µã×íÃ ÉßU ØVMÆ¢ÖÈçÎxá Îøß‚ Õà¿í ÎcâØßÏÎÞAß Ø¢øfßAáæÎK ÕÞ·íÆÞÈÎÞÃá ¼Üçø~ÏÞµáKÄí.</shortDescription>
</item> 
</category> 
<category name="Sports"> 
<item> 
<oid>2750</oid> 
<title>dÖàÖÞLí ÕàIá¢ ¿à¢ §LcÏßW</title> 
<thumbImage>http://122.248.234.55/v3/repository/images/news/sreesan_thuthumb_2750.jpg</thumbImage> 
<shortDescription>§¢±Ií Éøc¿ÈJßÈáU §LcX dµßAxí ¿àÎßW ÎÜÏÞ{ß ÄÞø¢ dÖàÖÞLá¢</shortDescription>
</item> 
<item> 
<oid>2749</oid> 
<title>µbßçxÞÕ çÈ¿ß</title> 
<thumbImage>http://122.248.234.55/v3/repository/images/news/sp-kvitova_thuthumb_2749.jpg</thumbImage> 
<shortDescription>ÎøßÏ ×ùçMÞÕæÏ ÉùMß‚ µbßçxÞÕÏÞÃí ÉáÄßÏ ÕßOßZÁX ÕÈßÄÞ ºÞ¢ÉcX</shortDescription>
</item> 
<item> 
<oid>2748</oid> 
<title>¥V¼aàÈ, ÙÞÕâ øfæMGá!</title> 
<thumbImage>http://122.248.234.55/v3/repository/images/news/sp-backheel_thuthumb_2748.jpg</thumbImage> 
<shortDescription>çµÞM ¥çÎøßA ¥V¼aàÈÏáæ¿ ¿âVÃæÎaÞµáæÎK æÉÞÄá ÇÞøÃÏÞÃí ©Æí¸Þ¿È ÎWØøJßW ÉÞ{ßÏÄí.</shortDescription>
</item> 
</category>
```

How to parse this xml file? there is two category "politics" and "sports". how can I define it in parser didStartElement and parser didEndElement. I had tried, but I can't separate category and its values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [NSXMLParser](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

It's a clean an easy to use API, [here is an example.](http://homepages.ius.edu/RWISMAN/C490/html/nsxmlparser.htm)

Or you can also try with CoreFoundation given an NSMutableData. [here is the example](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=244288).

Just Cocoa? [So try this](http://weblog.bignerdranch.com/?p=48)!

Comment: But sir i just want to know how to define this in didstart and didend

Comment: Here you have nipin http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/40819-parsing-xml-using-nsxmlparser.html

Answer (score -1):

Maybe look at the [*Document Object Model (DOM)*](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model). [Tutorial (quick google)](http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml)

Comment: i just want to know how to define this in didstart and didend delegate